# App.Config MessageEndpointMappings not working in NSB 3.3.8

Tags: nservicebus

In version 3.2.6 of NSB I had my endpoints mapped in my app config like this:

```
<UnicastBusConfig>
  <MessageEndpointMappings>
    <add Messages="Foo.Bar.Baz1, Foo.Interfaces" Endpoint="Foo.Bar.Monitor" />
    <add Messages="Foo.Bar.Baz2, Foo.Interfaces" Endpoint="Foo.Bar.Monitor" />
    <add Messages="Foo.Bar.Baz3, Foo.Interfaces" Endpoint="Foo.Bar.Monitor" />
  </MessageEndpointMappings>
</UnicastBusConfig>
```

This worked fine. When I upgraded to NSB 3.3.8 I saw that the API for endpointmappings had changed, and that in particular, [the `Messages` attribute was deprecated](https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/blob/master/Samples/PubSub/Subscriber1/App.config), so I tried to port my code to one of the new methods. **None of them work**. Here are the three different methods I tried:

```
<UnicastBusConfig>
  <MessageEndpointMappings>
    <add Assembly="Foo.Interfaces" Endpoint="Foo.Bar.Monitor" />
  </MessageEndpointMappings>
</UnicastBusConfig>
```

```
<UnicastBusConfig>
  <MessageEndpointMappings>
    <add Assembly="Foo.Interfaces" Namespace="Foo.Bar" Endpoint="Foo.Bar.Monitor" />
  </MessageEndpointMappings>
</UnicastBusConfig>
```

```
<UnicastBusConfig>
  <MessageEndpointMappings>
    <add Assembly="Foo.Interfaces" Type="Foo.Bar.Baz1" Endpoint="Foo.Bar.Monitor" />
    <add Assembly="Foo.Interfaces" Type="Foo.Bar.Baz2" Endpoint="Foo.Bar.Monitor" />
    <add Assembly="Foo.Interfaces" Type="Foo.Bar.Baz3" Endpoint="Foo.Bar.Monitor" />
  </MessageEndpointMappings>
</UnicastBusConfig>
```

Using any of these methods, when I try to send a `Baz1` I get an `InvalidOperationException: No destination specified for message(s): Foo.Bar.Baz1`.

It's worth noting that if I intentionally put in a typo in my type name (e.g. `Foo.Bar.Bazzzzz1`), NSB correctly faults during startup when it can't find the specified type, indicating that *something* must be happening to the ones that have no typos.

I *can* work around this issue by directly specifying my endpoint as a parameter to `Send`, but [NSB recommends not doing that](http://support.nservicebus.com/customer/portal/articles/862387-how-do-i-specify-to-which-destination-a-message-will-be-sent-).

**So my question is**: Am I still doing something wrong in my configuration, or is this truly a bug in NSB 3.3.8?

Comment: I have the same issues. Did you solve it?

Comment: @Algirdas No. In fact we ended up abandoning NServiceBus because it was so buggy from release to release. We moved to [MassTransit](http://masstransit-project.com/) and our lives have been much better ever since.